# How do you hide a UITextField Background image using code?

Tags: ios, swift

Using the storyboard, I set a UITextView with a background image by default so that it will show with the text field(bg color is clear).  There is an instance where I want the text to show, but the background image to be hidden.

I have tried several functions from other answers I've found without much success.

This is the closest I've found, but it just sets the background color behind the image to clear.

```
    text.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0)
```

If it is not possible to use one class reference I can create an image with the same constraints and use them together, but I'd like to keep it to one for simplicity.

**Edit**
A few more details in response to the comments.

1) An image can be set to a UITextView using the Background option in the attributes inspector on storyboard

2) I'm just learning Swift and I'm using the code for a simple tic-tac-toe app.  I realize there may be easier ways but I want to solve this problem this way if possible.  For a winning message, I want the text box background to have a festive background image.  For a draw, I want text only without a background.  I have considered adding an additional image and adding a simple .hidden = true line, but it would add a component to my storyboard and code (trying to minimize objects and code this way).

3) My text box is called "winner", so during the gameplay

```
    winner.hidden = true
```

I would like to do something like:

```
    winner.hidden = false
    winner.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

The above code works for regular image views - I haven't found anything for backgrounds on UITextViews though.

Comment: are you looking for `text.borderStyle = .None`

Comment: How did you “set a UITextView with a background image”?

Answer (score 0):

Could use a UIImage within the textfield as your background and toggle it with true or false?

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourImage: UIImage!
yourImage.hidden = true
yourImage.hidden = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more code to show us?

I would A. subclass the text field with a background image property and B. In the didBeginEditing delegate method would hide the image. That's the method which is called when the user starts typing.